# How to connect oracle database in python irrespective of operating system

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to write a python script using cx_oracle module for perform oracle database connection. But during the execution, I found it needs oracle instant client to establish a connection. Currently, I'm developing the script in ubuntu but there is a chance to run the same in windows. So I'm confused about the implementation. Could someone please suggest the best way to connect oracle database irrespective the platform

Answer (score 1):

You will always need an OS-specific library or client of some kind. Either the Oracle Instant Client or a Java JDK/JDBC library or both. If you want OS-independence then you would need to interact with the DB through REST calls or something like that instead of making a persistent connection. Otherwise you have to interact with the OS networking stack at some point, which requires OS-specific libraries.